# PHP URL parameter isn't passed using form action with GET method

Tags: php, wordpress

I am facing the problem in WordPress. I passed the value from 1st page to 2nd page (here app-2) which shows the result (by using inspector) but when the form is submitted URL shows only

```
"app-2/?Screens=30"
```

But

```
"app-2/?type=app&Screens=30"
```

is meant to show. Why does this happen? Is it something to do with 'GET' method?

N.B: $_GET['type'] works perfectly.

```
<form action="app-2/?
type=<?php $type=$_GET['type']; echo $type;?>
&Screens=<?php echo $_POST['Screens'];?>" 
method="GET">

  <input type="radio" name="Screens" value="3 - 5" required/>
  <input type="radio" name="Screens" value="16 - 30" />

 <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Is it a typo with form action: $_POST['Screens'] and you mean $_GET['Screens'] instead?

Comment: Maybe htaccess is rewriting the url.

Comment: @BenRoob No. He is using `$_POST['Screens']` and appends it to the URL, so afterwards he can access it like `$_GET['...']`. It doesn't make too much sense though because he has a field with the name 'Screens' aswell that is required.

Comment: This form submit not possible.

Comment: actually, I used `$_POST['Screens']` to get the form radio button value and used `$_GET['type']` to get the previous URL parameter 'type'

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
<?php
$parameters = "";
$parameters .= "?type=".(isset($_GET["type"])?$_GET["type"]:'')."&Screens=".isset($_GET["Screens"])?$_GET["Screens"]:'';

?>
<form action="app-2/<?=parameters?>" 
method="GET">
```

Comment: this is result for the above script?i'm pretty sure you are showing me some other result with your code.try the above one and show me the that url.

Comment: 1st of all your code has syntax error then I try to resolve that and get that output. Here's the error of your code `Error: There is 1 more closing curly braces '}' found. This count is unaware if curly braces are inside of a string. PHP Syntax Check: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in your code on line 3
$parameters .= "?type=".(isset($_GET["type"])?$_GET["type"]:'')."&Screens=".<?=isset($_GET["Screens"])?$_GET["Screens"]:''?>;}
PHP Syntax Check: Errors parsing your code`

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(".submit-form").submit(function(e){
   e.preventDefault;
   window.location.href = 'app-2/'+$(".submit-form").serialize();
   return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="GET" class='submit-form'>
   
  <input type="hidden" name="type" value=<?php echo $_GET['type']; ?> 
  <input type="radio" name="Screens" value="3 - 5" required/>
  <input type="radio" name="Screens" value="16 - 30" />

 <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

You can try with javascript Please check answer it will helps you :)

Comment: i just tried this example and it is working good.. url will be like `xxxxxxxxxx/app-2/type=test&Screens=16+-+30`